# ScrollViewer Actual Height Returning Incorrect Value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawing, scrollview

No matter what I do I cant make the line extent to the bottom of the scrollview :(

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Name="dock"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        LastChildFill="True"
        Focusable="True">
        <Menu
            Name="menuBar"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
            BorderBrush="Silver"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem
                Header="File" />
            <MenuItem
                Header="Options">
                <MenuItem
                    Header="Personal Info" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
                Header="View" />
            <MenuItem
                Header="About" />
        </Menu>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtInput"
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            Height="23"
            SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            BorderThickness="1,2,1,1"
            KeyDown="txtInput_KeyDown"
            TabIndex="1" />
        <ListBox
            Name="lstUsers"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Width="160"
            BorderThickness="2,0,0,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray" />
        <ScrollViewer
            Name="lstMessagesScroll"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl
                Name="lstMessages"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
    <Line
        StrokeThickness="0.5"
        X1="116"
        X2="116"
        Y1="23"
        Stroke="Gainsboro"
        Y2="{Binding ElementName=lstMessagesScroll, Path=ActualHeight}" />
</Grid>
```

Any tips?

Comment: You would need to post some more code. As is - when I put your code in a Grid in a blank app (putting opening <DockPanel> tag at the beginning) - the line does stretch to the bottom.

Comment: Perhaps the DockPanel is not set to stretch to the bottom of its parent - maybe it has a non-zero bottom Margin value or its VerticalAlignment isn't set to Stretch.

Comment: Hi sorry, I thought it may have confused the issue, but yes I posted some more.

Comment: Shouldn't Y2 be ActualHeight + 23?

Comment: @mrpyo No idea how to do additions in XAML.

Comment: So do it in code behind, on resize event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In playing around with your XAML I found that if you bind the Height to same element and set Y1 to 0 it will act the way that I believe you are expecting.

```
<Line
    StrokeThickness="0.5" 
    X1="116" 
    X2="116" 
    Y1="0"
    Stroke="Gainsboro"     
    Y2="{Binding ElementName=lstMessagesScroll, Path=ActualHeight }"
    Height="{Binding ElementName=lstMessagesScroll, Path=ActualHeight }" />
```

[image]

Comment: Working perfectly now thanks! Sorry for the simple mistake I am brand new to WPF.

Comment: @MuhammadA It is more of a quirk than a mistake, I figured it out by playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly - it's just that you are not taking the Menu into the account.